# Creating workspace component Library with vite for monorepo react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, vite, monorepo

I currently have a monorepo and I am looking to export all of my components into a new vite app within that repo and export the components into the current application

When I look online everything suggests to publish this to npm - however I want these components to live within the workspace

Does anyone know if this is possible and how I go about exporting, I keep getting the following error

`./src/amp/components/TableAnswer/TableAnswer.js Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../../../../doorframe/src/components/door/EdiTable which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`

My current filepath looks like

```
src -- 
    --- doorframe [new component lib with vite]
       ---src 
          ---main.jsx
    --- main [folder with 3 apps which are all inside one react application via routing] 
       ---src 
          ---App1
          ---App2
          ---App3
```

Im looking to import from doorframe into the child apps via something like

`import button from @doorframe`

I have tried exporting these and have had no luck

with package.json for doorframe looking like

```
  "name": "@doorframe",
  "author": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "doorframe: design system",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
```

and the main package.json importing this like

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@doorframe": "workspace:*",
```